# Image magick overlaying images

Tags: imagemagick

I have two images, one is the overlay, lets say Image A with transparency, and another image B, I have to place the overlay image A over image B, so that some part of image B is visible through the transparent part of image A, I also have to move the image B according to some parameters, How can I achieve this with image magick

Answer (score 11):

I was able to achieve it by the following command

```
composite -compose Dst_Over -geometry 520x320+20+80 image.jpeg overlay.png final.png
```

the key here `-compose Dst_Over`, which puts the image under the background (`overlay.png`) and the geometry options let you move the image.

Comment: This work but the output matches the overlay's dimensions.  Useful to specify output dims according to base layer

Comment: If your background is an animated GIF, you can do it with something like this: `convert animation.gif -coalesce -gravity NorthEast -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "transparent-watermark.png"' -layers Optimize final.gif`